# Element is hidden not working with css property

Tags: jquery

I want to check if an element is hidden but the code below is not working properly.

```
if ( $(element).css('display') = 'none' ){
// element is hidden
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey in your code you have to put ==

```
if( $(element).css('display') == 'none' ){

}
```

Also you can use

```
$("#idElement").is(":visible")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not working because you are using `=` you need to use `==`.

> `$(element).css('display') = 'none'` will cause error because you are trying to do an assignment operation.

More elegant solution.

```
if (!$(element).is(':visible')){
    // element is hidden
}
```